# html replace click event inside bxslider not working

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I'm using bxslider to contain images/video/etc and run into a snag.

I have an click event which should swap the contents of an html element and it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#placeholder" ).click(function() {
        $('#container').html('<div>this replaces the image</div>');
    });
});
```

When it's outside of the bxslider it works fine, but when it's inside it looks like it's refreshing the page but that's it. The bxslider works fine. I've checked firebug's console and it's not giving me any errors.

How can I get this html replacement working?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so we can better understand the problem?

Comment: Is the #placeholder element dynamically created?

Comment: created a basic fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trundles/pda3z391/10/  I've discovered that if the html replacement stuff is in the first slide it works, but not if it's in the second